# CANT_REREAD: Format string in Celery .%h

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

In my supervisor file I have added `.%h` to the end of my worker names (celery) to make them unique. For example:

```
[program:celery_worker]
directory = /srv/project/
command=celery -A tasks worker -l info -n default.%h
```

However, since added this change supervisor will not longer update or start giving the error:

> ,  "CANT_REREAD: Format string 'celery -A tasks worker -l info -n default.%h' for 'command' is badly formatted""> file: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/supervisorctl.py line: 947

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an underdocumented issue: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/291

Just use `%` again to escape it:

```
command=celery -A tasks worker -l info -n default.%%h
```

Comment: It _is_ mentioned in the [documentation page for workers](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html) :)

Comment: It is mentioned as a commentary in [supervisord docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=escape%20percent)

Comment: % must be escaped even when % is enclosed in single quotes.